# Encoded string decoding

Tags: encoding, hash, decoding, string-decoding

Got a string in JSON, definitly encoded. The question is: if there any way to find out which method's been used to encode it an how to make it readable again?

```
#2aHR0cDovL2RhdGEtaGQuZGF0YWxvY2sucnUvZmkybG0vYS8vNDQwMjg1L2hkX1RoZS5XYWxraW5nLkRlYWQuUzExRTAwLjcyMHAucnVzLkxvc3RGaWxtLlRWLmExLjE2LjExLjIyLm1wNCBvciBodHRwOi8vdGVtcC1jZG4uZGF0YWxvY2sucnUvZmkybG0vYS8vNDQwMjg1LzdmX1RoZS5XYWxraW5nLkRlYWQuUzExRTAwLjcyMHAucnVzLkxvc3RGaWxtLlRWLmExLjE2LjExLj\/\/b2xvbG8=IyLm1wNA==
```

The whole object looks like:

```
{"title":"1 \u0441\u0435\u0440\u0438\u044f SD<br>","file":"#2aHR0cDovL3RlbXAtY2RuLmRhdGFsb2NrLnJ1L2ZpMmxtL2UwMTRjZmU2YTMxNWY4Mjg4MmVlMTJiYzk2OTM0NTA5LzdmX\/\/b2xvbG8=1Rlc3QubmEuYmVyZW1lbm5vc3QuczAzLmUwMS5XRUItRExSaXAuMjVLdXptaWNoLmExLjE2LjExLjIyLm1wNA==","subtitle":"","galabel":"34382_880414","id":"1","vars":"880414"}
```

Comment: Could be base64 (RFC 2045 variant, so many online decoders will not accept it), but the result does not look familiar to me. Is there no documentation of what is supposed to be in that JSON string?

Comment: it should be a link to a file

Comment: It doesn't look like a link, it looks like it could be the file though, was this part of a data url?

Comment: no.. the whole object looks like:


{"title":"1 \u0441\u0435\u0440\u0438\u044f SD<br>","file":"#2aHR0cDovL3RlbXAtY2RuLmRhdGFsb2NrLnJ1L2ZpMmxtL2UwMTRjZmU2YTMxNWY4Mjg4MmVlMTJiYzk2OTM0NTA5LzdmX\/\/b2xvbG8=1Rlc3QubmEuYmVyZW1lbm5vc3QuczAzLmUwMS5XRUItRExSaXAuMjVLdXptaWNoLmExLjE2LjExLjIyLm1wNA==","subtitle":"","galabel":"34382_880414","id":"1","vars":"880414"}

Comment: I can't really make anything of it then, best I could do is decode it to 225 bytes starting with `0xD9, 0xA1, 0xD1, 0xD1, 0xC0, 0xE8, 0xBC, 0xBD, 0x91, 0x85, 0xD1, 0x84, 0xB5, 0xA1, 0x90, 0xB9` (too long to post the whole thing) which I don't recognize the format of